# SQL Select with multiple AND and OR's

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, where-clause

I'm sitting with a logic issues and I'm just confusing myself more and more.

Example table

### ID | CustID | Task  | Confirmed | Cancelled | Completed

1  |   20   | text  |    1      |     0     |     0
2  |   20   | text  |    1      |     1     |     0
3  |   20   | text  |    1      |     0     |     1
4  |   17   | text  |    0      |     1     |     0
5  |   17   | text  |    1      |     0     |     0
6  |   20   | text  |    1      |     NULL  |     NULL
7  |   20   | text  |    0      |     1     |     NULL

I wish to select all tasks for custID = 20 and are confirmed=1. If the task is cancelled=1 or completed=1, do not return the record.

In this case, returned rows would be 1 and 6.

My query thus far is

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE    
 (CustID = 20 AND Confirmed = 1 AND Cancelled <> 1 AND Completed <> 1) OR
 (CustID = 20 AND Confirmed = 1 AND Cancelled = 1 AND Completed <> 1) OR
 (CustID = 20 AND Confirmed = 1 AND Cancelled <> 1 AND Completed = 1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can simplify that to:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE CustID = 20
  AND Confirmed = 1
  AND (Cancelled <> 1 OR Cancelled IS NULL)
  AND (Completed <> 1 OR Completed IS NULL)
```

You have to be careful (and very explicit) when comparing real values with NULLs, since equalities and inequalities both exclude them.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE    
    CustID = 20 AND Confirmed = 1 AND NOT (Cancelled = 1 OR Completed = 1)
```

Comment: Also works, just need to include checking for NULL like above solution, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM thk_basvuru WHERE thk_status in (8,23,33) or thk_olo_status not in (4,6,9,11,12)
```